# Max client or Server Hard Limit not found in httpd.conf file apache

Tags: php, apache

I'm using wamp in my system. I'm facing  some issues in my project dicussed here [click here to see the discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854062/socket-error-problem). Now i have to increase the connection limit. I searched the Max client and Server Hard Limit in my httpd.conf file but nothing found. Is i have to add any other extra module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is defined in the mpm_common so it's really common for all mpm modules.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients

Just add it into httpd.conf if it's not already there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Under which module i have to place the Maxclient??

Comment: Under no module. httpd.conf has no module sections. It's linear. Place where you want.